# Are inactive calories on google fit wrong?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

With "inactive cal" is google fit talking about "basic metabolic rate" ?

Because the bmr is supposed to be costant but fit gives me a different number of "inactive cal" every day...

Someone can explain me why? It pass from 1500 to 2100 depending on my activities. I can't understand why, especially because bmr is the amount of calories you burn without doing activities so it should not be related to them.

So what is exactly "inactive cal" and why it changes day by day?

This is happening to all the people I know

Thank you in advance!:)

Answer (score 2):

Inactive calories are your basal metabolic rate multiplied by the amount of time that Google Fit thinks you spend at rest. The more time you spend exercising, the less time you spend at rest, and thus the lower your inactive calories.

Your inactive calories may also change because your basal metabolic rate changes (most likely because you've logged a new weight).

Answer (score 1):

"inactive cal" is the amount of calories burned without google fit noticing any activity. This can be very inaccurate because no calorie tracking app is perfect.

Comment: Thanks! Thus if I go out for a run there's no bmr burning but only the run's burned calories ?

I do not think that stop the bmr calculation during an activity is the right and scientific approach to the consumption of calories.

BMR is a continuos calories's consumption during the day, quite accurately estimated with some equations like the Harris-Benedict's one.

Am I wrong if I say that at the end of the day we have burned our specific BMR plus the calories of our activities and sports?

My idea seems to be different form the google fit approach..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Google Fit calculation can be right. On days when I do more walking, Google Fit shows that I have burned less overall calories than on less active days.

It looks to me like it overcompensates for the rest periods. If I was going to believe the calorie values provided by Google Fit, then in order to maximise my calories burned in a day, I would need to do less exercise.